# do-while loop evaluating two if and else if statements. One regardless of inputs. (C)

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while

Below is my code, basically I'm trying to get my do-while loop to run as long as the if or else if statements are evaluated as true.  But every time I run it, it works except that it always prints the 2 else if statement "the value you entered is less than 1", regardless of the user input.  I am completely out of ideas as to why its wrong.

```
int get_input(void){

    int Value_1;
    int status;
    do{

        //Ask user to enter an odd number between 1 and 9
        printf("Enter any odd number between 1 and 9 inclusive> \n");
        //Store entered number in Value_1

        status = scanf(" %d", &Value_1);
        is_valid(Value_1);
  }
    while (is_valid()!=1);
    return(Value_1);
}

int is_valid(int status){

    if(status==2 || status==4 || status==6|| status==8){

        printf("The value you entered is not odd>\n");
        return(0);
    }
    else if(status > 9){
        printf("the value you entered is greater than 9> \n");
        return(0);
}
    else if(status < 1){
        printf("the value you entered is less than 1> \n");
        return(0);
}
    else{
        return(1);
    }
}

int main(void){


    int Value_1;
    int status;


    Value_1=get_input();
    printf("%d", Value_1);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code even *compiles*? You are calling a function taking an argument with *no* arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
is_valid(Value_1);
```

and change

```
while (is_valid()!=1);
```

to

```
while (is_valid(Value_1)!=1);
```

The problem you are getting is that in your while, `is_valid()` does not have any argument, and that causes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

In while statement, you are calling the function without the argument. Make that
like this.

```
 while (is_valid(value_1)!=1);
```

Remove the calling inside the block. Because you are calling the same function two times. This is the reason it printing twice.

And make the function prototype of the function, before this,

```
int is_valid(int status);
int get_input(void){
 ...
 ...
}
```

compiler doesn't how the function were defined. If you place this you will get this error.

```
too few arguments to function ‘is_valid’
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
do{

        //Ask user to enter an odd number between 1 and 9
        printf("Enter any odd number between 1 and 9 inclusive> \n");
        //Store entered number in Value_1

        status = scanf(" %d", &Value_1);
        is_valid(Value_1);
  }
  while (is_valid()!=1);
```

with

```
do{

        //Ask user to enter an odd number between 1 and 9
        printf("Enter any odd number between 1 and 9 inclusive> \n");
        //Store entered number in Value_1

        scanf(" %d", &Value_1);
       status =  is_valid(Value_1);
  }
    while (status!=1);
```